# Get VID/ PID of printer using C# with unknown device id

Tags: c#, .net, usb, printers, deviceid

I have a usb printer. I don't know how to take device id also. I want to take vid/ pid using c# code. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
using System.Management;
ManagementObjectSearcher myPrinterObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Printer");

foreach (ManagementObject obj in myPrinterObject.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name  -  " + obj["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Network  -  " + obj["Network"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Availability  -  " + obj["Availability"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Is default printer  -  " + obj["Default"]);
    Console.WriteLine("DeviceID  -  " + obj["DeviceID"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Status  -  " + obj["Status"]);
    
    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(obj["Name"].ToString().Length, '='));
}
```

The WMI properties are:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer?redirectedfrom=MSDN

You can also wrap the manufacturer DLL with a C++ wrapper and then call that from your C# application seamlessly however this will could take you a long time to write!

Comment: Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found